# Can't add multiple same child views to a parent view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

i want to ask is my logic acceptable? I want to add a views(LinearLayouts) by a trigger from an action bar button, the tab2.refresh() was called

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_edit_profile:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),EditProfileActivity.class);
            //  startActivity(intent);


            break;
        case R.id.action_refresh:

            //  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),EditProfileActivity.class);
            //  startActivity(intent);

            tab2.refresh();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the method

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

static LinearLayout LL;
static LinearLayout parent_linear;
Context context;
View v;

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

    context = getActivity();
    parent_linear = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.parent_linear);
    LL = new LinearLayout(context);

    return v;
}

private static void create_layout() {


    LL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.navbtns);
    LL.setClickable(true);
    LL.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
    LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LLParams.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);


}

public static void refresh() {
    create_layout();
    parent_linear.addView(LL);
}}
```

Please Help the log cat says like this, but i think i cannot do what it says because i want to add more than one identical view but it wants me to remove it -_-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: why is `create_layout` static ?

Comment: Because it is from a different class?

Comment: and? Also, why are you answering a question with another question ?

Comment: Because i'm not sure, i'm not that good... no need to be rude

Comment: remove the static modifier from `refresh` and `create_layout` and check if it still compiles

Comment: To be clear the first snippet is from a different class and the other is as well so why wouldn't i use static?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not quite sure what are you exactly trying to do, but in my understanding you're creating some kind of List of items, starting from an empty list and adding one every time the user presses the refresh button.
At least based on the names, this doesn't make so much sense since what you expect from a refresh button is to refresh the content, not add more, but let's just suppose this is just a naming problem and your button does have to add one more item.

If this is what you want to get, it sounds a lot like you should use a ListView or a RecyclerView instead of adding manually new layouts every time. You should define this layout as the items of the RecyclerView, and then add one item to the list and refresh the recyclerview to reflect the changes on the content.

Last but not least, if you still want to do it your way because of any reason, your exact problem is that a child view can't have more than one parent as the log precisely says. And the solution would be to actually create a new LinearLayout every time you call the refresh() method, since currently you're referencing the same object many times and creating it on the onCreateView method, that's just called once.

But again, try using a RecyclerView like in this example, it seems to be to proper way to solve your problem:
http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example